# Database connection for Quartz scheduler

Tags: database, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am new to Quartz scheduler. I want to connect the database to scheduler... How am I connect?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about it. It would have been great if you had shown [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), but I'll go with instruction:

1. Create your `Job` (org.quartz.Job) class.
2. In `execute` method, have your JDBC connection created and use it.

That's all.

Now, if you meant to know about JDBCJObStore, there is a great [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/) to learn from.

Comment: what do you mean by "have your JDBC connection created"? That is the main problem, all the connection info should come from somewhere (from config or persistence.xml) and inside de Job it´s no possible to inject any managed bean (doesnt matter the scope).
I am one of those who has this exactly same problem, inside the execute I need to run some database operations and until now no success!